# How to prevent prevent composer from immediately printing stderr to stdout

Tags: php, shell, composer-php

## Goal

Stop composer install from running if `.env` is missing

## `composer.json` snippet

```
"scripts": {
    "pre-install-cmd": "[[ -a .env ]] || echo '.env missing. please create .env' 1>&2 && exit 1;"
},
```

## Output

```
$ composer install
.env missing. please create .env
Script [[ -a .env ]] || >&2 echo '.env missing. please create .env' && exit 1; handling the pre-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: .env missing. please create .env
```

## Desired

Same as above but w/o cruft, in particular the immediately-echoed & redundant `.env missing. please create .env`

## Question

**How do I prevent composer from immediately echoing that string?** It even happens with the `-q` switch

Comment: Your script returns an error correctly, the composer should have logic to stop. Can the script generate a working .env when it is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how this is supposed to work?

You are asking Composer to run your script. That script creates output, which is displayed.

Now the return code from that script signals an error condition. And the rest is up to Composer. It is a good idea to inform the user which script has failed (which explains the line directly after the echoed output), because scripts don't have to echo anything, and you are free to run more than one script line there.

And then the general Composer error display kicks in another time, stating once more that the error condition produced some output.

Now I wonder what you want to suppress. That first line? Then don't echo anything.

Any later lines? No luck, this is how Composer handles errors in general.

Stepping back and looking at the bigger picture, I'd ask why Composer shouldn't be allowed to install dependencies? Composer does not need that file - and if your code needs it, it should provide the user with a simpler way of creating that file, or check it's absence and react either with a sensible default value assumption, or refuse to work - which would enable you to better control the circumstances of displaying an error message.

Comment: What I want to suppress is the 2x output of the same string. Does that make sense? I echo it *to stderr* which typically does not hit stdout, that's the point of redirection unless I'm way off.  It looks like composer directs both errors & output to stdout & then reports errors a second time on fail.  ANYWAY to clarify I want the error output 1x.